# seaborn relplot x values adjustment

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I have two parameters from panda's dataframe, `bmi` and `heart_disease`. I want to show them with `relplot`, it shows information that other plots lose. I used this simple code:

```
facetObj = sns.relplot(x="heart_disease", y="bmi", data=data); 
facetObj;
```

The `heart_disease` parameter only has two values: `1` or `0`. However, the plot gave me a whole range of numbers from 0 to 1. How do I make it only 0 and 1 ?

[image]

Comment: nor an expert on seaborn, but maybe this answer helps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66481168/17270192

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your `heart_disease` column is integer. To change, you can do one of the following:

1. Change the heart_disease column to string **before** plotting (before sns.relplot)

```
data['heart_disease'] = data['heart_disease'].astype(str)
```

2. **After** plotting, you can use set `x_ticks` and set `x_ticklables` to show just 0 and 1. Note you need to set the plot as below (g=sns.replot(...))

```
g = sns.relplot(x="heart_disease", y="bmi", data=data)
g.ax.set_xticks([0,1])
```

**The plot**

[image]

Comment: Note that [`sns.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) is a figure-level function. It doesn't return an `ax`, but a `FacetGrid`.  One way to grab the `ax` for facet grids with only one subplot is via `g.ax` (with `g = sns.relplot(...)`).

Comment: Thanks @JohanC. Initially, I did do the `g=sns.relplot(...)` and then the `g.ax.set_ticks(..)` and `set_ticklables(..)`. But, this method appeared to cut down a step. Is there any harm/unintended consequences of using this method?

Comment: The harm is that it introduces confusion. What you call `ax` isn't an axes object, which makes that functions such as `ax.set_ticks()` wouldn't work.  Please don't name the result of a figure-level function `ax`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JohanC for the info... I have updated accordingly. Can get a little confusing as these update  ticks and axes labels, but is a figure-level function.

Comment: Indeed, calling `g.set(xticks=[0,1])` is confusing. Why not just `g.ax.set_xticks([0,1])`? Note that you don't need `set_xticklabels` here, as 0 and 1 are the defaults in this situation.

Comment: Yes indeed. Much clearer!! Made the updates